# Can I change NGINX location dynamicly?

Tags: nginx

```
listen       8087;
location /file/<file_number> {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081/file/<file_number>;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I can change file number in my browser address line:
http://0.0.0.0:8087/file/1 or http://0.0.0.0:8087/file/2, etc
What should I do to use this opportunity?

Comment: Try: `location /file/ { proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081; ... }`

Comment: This is very basic proxy_pass material. I suggest you check nginx’s online manual at nginx.org